# Setting the width of a header and a cell of a gridview

Tags: asp.net, css, gridview

i have this page that displays a gridview with 16 columns. this gridview is horizontally scrollable and is designed with CSS. my problem is, whenever i try to set the width, both ItemStyle-Width and HeaderStyle-Width, it wont affect the width.

Here is my CSS:

```
.mGrid { 
    background-color: #fff; 
    margin: 5px 0 10px 0; 
    border: solid 1px #525252; 
    border-collapse:collapse;
    font-family: Calibri;
    font-size: 12px; 
    white-space:nowrap;
    table-layout:auto;
}

.hideGridColumn
{
    display:none;
}

.mGrid td { 
    padding: 2px; 
    border: solid 1px #c1c1c1; 
    color: #717171;    
    white-space:nowrap;
    table-layout:auto;
    font-family: Microsoft Sans Serif;
    font-size: 0.9em;
}
.mGrid th { 
    padding: 4px 2px; 
    color: #fff; 
    background: #424242 url(grd_head.png) repeat-x top; 
    border-left: solid 1px #525252; 
    font-size: 0.9em;
    font-family: Microsoft Sans Serif;
    text-align: center;
}
.mGrid .alt { background: #fcfcfc url(grd_alt.png) repeat-x top; }
.mGrid .pgr { background: #424242 url(grd_pgr.png) repeat-x top; }
.mGrid .pgr table { margin: 5px 0; }
.mGrid .pgr td { 
    border-width: 0; 
    padding: 0 6px; 
    border-left: solid 1px #666; 
    font-weight: bold; 
    color: #fff; 
    line-height: 12px; 
 }   
.mGrid .pgr a { color: #666; text-decoration: none; }
.mGrid .pgr a:hover { color: #000; text-decoration: none; }
.GridDock
{
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    width: 200px;
    padding: 0 0 17px 0;
}
```

And an excerpt of the ASP.net Code:

```
<div id="dvScreenWidth" visible="false">
        <div class="GridDock" id="dvGridWidth">
             <asp:GridView ID="gvResults" runat="server" 
                      GridLines="None"
                      CssClass="mGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
                      AllowPaging="true" PagerStyle-CssClass="pgr"
                      PageSize="30">
                <PagerSettings Position="Top" />
                <PagerStyle CssClass="pgr" />
                <Columns>
                     <asp:BoundField DataField="DateAndTimeInspected" ItemStyle-Height="35" HeaderStyle-Height="35" HeaderText="INSPECTION TIMESTAMP" SortExpression="DateAndTimeInspected" />
                     <asp:BoundField DataField="QA Inspector" ItemStyle-Height="35" HeaderStyle-Height="35"  HeaderText="QA INSPECTOR" SortExpression="QA Inspector" />
                     <asp:BoundField DataField="FT_TESTED/UNTESTED" ItemStyle-Height="35" HeaderStyle-Height="35" HeaderText="TESTED / UNTESTED" SortExpression="FT_TESTED/UNTESTED" />
                     <asp:BoundField DataField="productname" ItemStyle-Height="35" HeaderStyle-Height="35" HeaderText="DEVICE" SortExpression="productname" />
                     <asp:BoundField DataField="containername" ItemStyle-Height="35" HeaderStyle-Height="35" HeaderText="LOT NUMBER" SortExpression="containername" />
                     <asp:BoundField DataField="packagetype" ItemStyle-Height="35" HeaderStyle-Height="35" HeaderText="PACKAGE TYPE" SortExpression="packagetype" />
                     <asp:BoundField DataField="datecode" ItemStyle-Height="35" HeaderStyle-Height="35" HeaderText="DATE CODE" SortExpression="datecode" />
                     <asp:BoundField DataField="assysite" ItemStyle-Height="35" HeaderStyle-Height="35" HeaderText="ASSEMBLY SITE" SortExpression="assysite" />
                     <asp:BoundField DataField="FT_SUBCON_TEST" ItemStyle-Height="35" HeaderStyle-Height="35" HeaderText="FINAL TEST SITE" SortExpression="FT_SUBCON_TEST" />
                     <asp:BoundField DataField="moveoutqty" ItemStyle-Height="35" HeaderStyle-Height="35" HeaderText="LOT QUANTITY" SortExpression="moveoutqty" />
                     <asp:BoundField DataField="FT_IQA_SAMPLE_SIZE" ItemStyle-Height="35" HeaderStyle-Height="35" HeaderText="SAMPLE SIZE" SortExpression="FT_IQA_SAMPLE_SIZE" />
                     <asp:BoundField DataField="FT_IQA_SAMPLE_REJECT" ItemStyle-Height="35" HeaderStyle-Height="35" HeaderText="SAMPLE REJECT" SortExpression="FT_IQA_SAMPLE_REJECT" />
                     <asp:BoundField DataField="FT_REJECT CATEGORY" ItemStyle-Height="35" HeaderStyle-Height="35" HeaderText="REJECT CATEGORY" SortExpression="FT_REJECT CATEGORY" />
                     <asp:BoundField DataField="FT_IQA_DISPOSITION" ItemStyle-Height="35" HeaderStyle-Height="35" HeaderText="IQA DISPOSITION" SortExpression="FT_IQA_DISPOSITION" />
                     <asp:BoundField DataField="FT_DMR#" ItemStyle-Height="35" HeaderStyle-Height="35" HeaderText="DMR NUMBER" SortExpression="FT_DMR#" />
                     <asp:BoundField DataField="Remarks" ItemStyle-Height="35" HeaderStyle-Height="35" HeaderText="REMARKS" SortExpression="Remarks" />
                </Columns>
             </asp:GridView>
        </div>
    </div> 

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function thirty_pc() {
            var height = $(window).height();
            var thirtypc = (100 * (height - 167)) / 100;
            thirtypc = parseInt(thirtypc) + 'px';
            $("#divContent").css('height', thirtypc);

        }

        $(document).ready(function() {
            thirty_pc();
            $(window).bind('resize', thirty_pc);


        });
        $(document).keypress(function(event) {
            if (event.which == 13) {
                $("#ctl00_cphContent_searchFilter_btnSearch").focus();
                $("#ctl00_cphContent_searchFilter_btnSearch").click();
            }
        });


        $(document).ready(function() {
           $('#dvGridWidth').width($('#dvScreenWidth').width());            
        });

    </script>
```

I will really appreciate any help you can give me. Thank you so much.

Comment: i don't see any ItemStyle-Width in your BoundField just height. or are you trying to set the width on css instead?

Comment: my bad vhinn. but even if i have tried to put on itemstyle-width, same width of the cell is being displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

width of every cell in a table adjusts automatically depending on the width of the table. try setting a fixed width in your table.

```
<asp:GridView Width="2000px"
```

or in CSS

```
.mGrid { 
    width: 2000px;
}

.mGrid td { 
    width: 6.25%; /* 100% / 16 = 6.25 */
}
```

Comment: hi vhinn this does work along another solution i have found. but i think i will use this.